# Cascade Updates with Math in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

I am building a database system that contains a number of columns with mathematical relations between them. For example (this is a chess game storage example that I made up), one column is called "num_pawns", one is called "num_nights", one is called "num_castles", and one is called "piece_score". The values in piece_score are determined by the formula: 1*(num_pawns) + 3*(num_knights) + 5*(num_castles). I would like to know how to set a rule that recalculates the value of piece_score whenever one of the other columns is updated. For example, in row 1 the respective values of the first three columns are {6, 2, 1} and a knight is removed {6, 1, 1}, the value of piece_score should automatically update from 17 to 14 after the value in the num_knights column is updated. I realize that it would probably be more efficient to do this in PHP or C, but I am designing my database model to be portable. It could be on a server with MySQL and PHP, or it could be on a mobile device with SQLite and Java. Is there any way to accomplish these kind of post-query updates using strictly SQL?

**Update**:

To clarify and elaborate on the above example, imagine two additional columns: score_rank and skill_level. The reason for the above computations is so that each row can be assigned a value in score_rank based on its score compared to the other rows (highest score gets 1, second gets 2, etc.). After a rank is assigned, the top 5 scores are given a value of 1 in skill_level, scores 6-10 are given a value of 2, 11-15 are given 3, etc. Is this comparison and ordering possible in SQL? I'm guessing that a trigger is the proper approach, but how could I execute the ordering and assignments over the whole table after an UPDATE? As I mentioned, this database needs to be portable and self-contained, so ideally the sorting and ranking abstraction should be maintained inside the database. That way queries can be made based off of the score_rank column or skill_level column with the assumption that these values reflect the current state of the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that a trigger is the most realistic solution to my problem. score_rank could be obtained for a certain row using

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_name AS p2 WHERE p2.num_pawns + 3*p2.num_knights + 5*num_castles > p1.num_pawns + 3*p2.num_knights + 5*num_castles) FROM table_name AS p1 where p1.rowid=x); where x is a rowid
```

Similarly, skill level can be calculated with this function by dividing by 5. This is probably the ideal way to do it, as it better fits the theoretical foundation of DRBs. However, with multiple columns being calculated in this way, the same values get recalculated each time they are needed, which can waste time as more columns are added. Therefore, I decided to use a trigger that would update score_rank after all necessary columns were filled, and then another trigger updates skill_level after score_rank is filled simply by dividing score_rank by 5, etc. This reduces redundant computations.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you have a really, really large table (think hundreds of thousands or millions of rows), you probably want to do this as a view and not by synchronizing the values.  The view would be something like this:

```
CREATE VIEW v 
AS 
  SELECT t.*, 
         ( num_paws * 1 + 3 * num_knights + 5 * num_castles ) AS piece_score 
  FROM   table t;
```

To do this as a separate column requires writing triggers to handle insert, updates, and deletes in each row.  Much easier to must calculate the value when you need it.  And, given that all the values are on one row, there is no performance advantage to storing the value in another column and keeping it up-to-date using a trigger.

Comment: I think that a trigger might be what I'm looking for, but I'm not sure. I clarified my question and expanded my example to more accurately reflect my situation. Could you take a look? Thanks.

Comment: Your answer got me halfway, but my answer explains the efficiency behind using a trigger in this case, as well as the implementation for ranking.